# How to create a file object using a system local path?

Tags: javascript

I get local directories for images in a csv file and the task is to upload them to a server with an api that deals with files or blobs ... so I need to convert those local directories to files or blobs (example: C:\folder\file).

I thought this is a common case that wouldn't take much time to dig up a solution for but it turned out to be a little bid of a confusion or maybe I am not yet really that flexible with JavaScript.

I tried this:

```
var file = File.createFromFileName("path/to/file");
```

based on the documentation ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Using_the_DOM_File_API_in_chrome_code))

I get : File.createFromFileName is not a function
The test is conducted on firefox.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob ?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a Server Language.

Comment: the file paths that you have in your `CSV` files are under a web accessible directory? or are you free to place those files there? what format is of the file paths in the `csv` file?

Comment: Where exactly are you running this from in Firefox? From the documentation you linked to: "This only works from privileged code, so web content can't do it."

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam the paths are put manually by the user in the csv file and they are punch of images.

Comment: what i am asking is are they accessible like `localhost/somdir/images/image1.png`

Comment: @AuxTaco I am running this locally. I guess the documentation is not what I am looking for then.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam The are locally saved in the machine where the user fills the csv file. i.e, "F:\\folder\file"

Comment: hmm so , they are absolute paths  to the file

Comment: question updated

Comment: So the javascript is ran from a normal html page? You simply can't, for obvious security reasons (Would you like any website be able to read all the content of your computer?). What you linked to is part of privileged `chrome://` API (i.e browser extensions). If you are not writing such an extension, this won't help you.

Comment: @Kaiido with my permission yes. The thing is. The website that I am building is like a control panel for a mobile application where the app admin uses excel sheets to upload data into the database so it can be reflected in the app. The data sometimes includes images saved in his/her local machine